# No menus on terminal

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal

When i was learning how to use terminal, i accidently click "Dont show menus" on terminal preferences, now i unable to access terminal preferences to re-enable menu bar.

Is there any command or easy way to revert change ?

Comment: Right clicking on the window itself gives drop-down menu, where you can check-uncheck "Show Menubar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to revert. Simply run following command on terminal, this should re-enable your "missing" menu bar :

```
gnome-terminal --show-menubar
```

Or right click at terminal and click "Show Menu bar"